# Rails calling redirect_to (or render) outside controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, rubygems, render, sidekiq

This may seem like a trivial issue, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere (this may because Rails frowns upon what I am doing).

I am using Sidekiq to handle background tasks (such as image processing, uploading, etc), and one they are finished I want to redirect the current page to another, or even better render out a partial.

My current code in the perform method looks something like this:

```
def perform(entry_id)
        @entry = Entry.find(entry_id)
        #Create, upload image, all stored in @file when complete

        if @file.save
            #render will go here
        else
            raise @file.inspect
        end
    end
```

So, I have tried several methods to do this such as:

```
render 'entry/new'
```

also

```
render :partial => 'entry/partial'
```

and

```
redirect_to @entry, notice: 'File Uploaded'
```

I even tried this horrible hack:

**entries_controller.rb**

```
# Called after the background task is completed
def self.done_loading(entry_id)
  @entry = Entry.find(entry_id)
  @entry.update
end
```

**worker.rb**

```
EntriesController.done_loading(entry_id)
```

What am I doing wrong?

References (stuff I looked up):
[When to use render vs redirect_to when handling error validations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070886/when-to-use-render-vs-redirect-to-when-handling-error-validations)

https://gist.github.com/1210155

http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=16885

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect/render after a background job is done you could use callbacks but you should re-think about doing this. To the user, they will have uploaded an image but since you are sending it to a background job you don't have a specific time-frame of when they will be executed. What if the job takes 2-5minutes to execute? The user will get redirected after 5 minutes?

Also, if you are doing uploads and processing of images you should take a look into

[jQuery File Uploads](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

[Railscasts #381 jQuery File Upload](http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload)

[Railscasts #383 Uploading to Amazon S3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3)

Comment: The reason why I am doing a background job is because it is going to be hosted on Heroku (which pretty explicitly tells you to run uploading as a background process). I don't exactly love the way it is all laid out at the moment, but for now the user would have a nice little loader .gif to keep them occupied and know that it is processing. I wanted to render out a partial so that it would update with the background task (done processing... now loading... etc.) I have looked at those two railscasts, and have used the jQuery file  uploader before, they are good, but i am trying to use sidekiq.

Comment: Which is a bit different, and I am just trying to work with paperclip as well. Overall, a little different, and in the end because it is a bit against the "rules of rails" it might not work. Figured I would try here before I went and re-factored everything though.

Answer (score 0):

You need the controller instance deep in something, so you could:

- put code in your ApplicationController to store the controller instance in thread local storage: `Thread.current[:controller] = self`
- Then you can call `Thread.current[:controller].redirect_to`

Horribly hacky, I know. I haven't tried this, but we do a similar thing for `User.current`.