# Rails doesn't find css files

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller with some function and their views. After the execution of this action

```
def register
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  if @user.register
    if @user.mailcode_type == 'custom'
      render :checkout
    else
      session[:user_id] = nil
      render :thankyou
    end
  else
    render :signup_first_step
  end
end
```

Rails doesn't find css files after the render. It looks for them in 127.0.0.1:3000/register. If i go to the same page without passing for register it loads css files correctly . These files are in app/assets/stylesheet.

This is my application.css:

```
*= require jquery.qtip.min
*= require css3buttons/without-reset
*= require magnific-popup
*= require_self
*= require_tree ./application
```

Comment: Show your `application.css` file

Comment: Unless you have something badly misconfigured, it's not looking for css at that path. View source in your browser on the rendered page -- what tags like `link rel="stylesheet"` are there?

Comment: Would be really helpful to also have your `views/layours/application.html.erb` file

Comment: I added my application.css file. In my application.html.erb file i have this line to call css: <%= stylesheet_link_tag  "application", :media => "all" %>

Answer (score 1):

That is because render is simply using the same stack(same memory object) that's why scripts aren't running, where as redirect creates a new object.

Use,

```
 redirect_to :checkout
```

For more info. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070886/when-to-use-render-vs-redirect-to-when-handling-error-validations)

Comment: This is incorrect. `redirect_to` has nothing to do with running scripts. `redirect_to` initiates a new http request, render doesn't. Neither case addresses the question.

Comment: here he wants to render the view page for checkout without going to the action. your action will take it to the action. secondly it is wrong. syntax issues.

Comment: My first explanation was theoretically incorrect, but "redirect_to" could fix his issue, also changed explanation.

Comment: @MarcoBompani does the above answer works.? changing render to redirect_to? because it must be going to checkout action now.

Comment: @MarcoBompani: I had this issue, I did used redirect_to to fix it.

Comment: Actually it works only in some case. If my if statement goes to render :signup_first_step i have the problem because i need a render there